# How do I use static variables for dynamic "each" functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a variable:

```
var numId = $('h3.pag').attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
```

This variable is supposed to get every `h3.pag` from my html and extract the number from the numbered class each one of them has: `pag1`, `pag2`, `pag3`... and so on.

I will use this numbers in the following code:

```
$("h3.pag"+numId).each(function() {
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('h3.pag'+numId+'::before','content: "TEST";');
});
```

In short, what I want to accomplish is to be able to extract the number of each one of my `h3`s and use them to apply that CSS rule for each one of them.

For now, the code is only affecting the FIRST `h3`. I suppose that the variable is static, so it stops on the first `h3` and keeps the value. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the startsWith [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get all `h3`'s that start with "pag": `h3[class^=pag]` and then parse the number from the classname of the current item:

```js
$("h3[class^=pag]").each(function() {
    // get the number out of the current class name
    var num = this.className.match(/pag([\d]+)/)[1];
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('h3.pag'+num+'::before','content: "TEST with JS - ";');
});
```

```css
h3[class^=pag]::after {
  content: ' - accomplished with css alone';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h3 class="pag1">Page 1</h3>
    <h3 class="pag2">Page 2</h3>
    <h3 class="pag3">Page 3</h3>
```

Though for this particular use case you could just use CSS as I demonstrated with my `::after` rule